# jQuery: Añadir estilos CSS dentro de .text()

Tags: jquery, css

Dado el siguiente código:

```
$('.encabezado-subestilo').children().text('Quizá también te pueda gustar...');
```

¿Hay alguna forma sencilla de que la palabra "gustar" aparezca en un color concreto?

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Por qué en vez de `text()` mejor usas `html()`? De esa forma puedes insertar un span con una clase o un style (si lo preferes). Algo como:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.encabezado-subestilo').children().html('Quizá también te pueda <span class="text-red">gustar</span>...');
});
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="encabezado-subestilo">
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

O:

```js
$('.encabezado-subestilo').children().html('Quizá también te pueda <span style="color: #ccc;">gustar</span>...');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="encabezado-subestilo">
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta pero para los ejemplos, stackoverflow-es cuanta con fragmentos ejecutables, en JS y HTML con ellos puedes agregar codigo ejecutable sin necesidad de poner enlaces que hacen lo mismo, aqui una ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help